# Does the mean shape from Generalized Procrustes analysis describe the average orientation of the set of shapes?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra

I have recently written my own version of the Generalized Procrustes Algorithm (GPA without scaling). To test my function, I input the vertices of a set of 3D ellipsoids with minor perturbations around a common major axis centered at the origin. However, the output of my function ignores this major axis and converges to the orientation of the first reference average shape (set to be the first ellipsoid in my set). Thus, while the result looks correct (see image 2), it is in actuality very dependent on what the first reference is set to. I do feel like this is an error in my implementation, which I simply took from this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Procrustes_analysis#:%7E:text=Generalized%20Procrustes%20analysis%20(GPA)%20is,surveys%2C%20interviews%2C%20or%20panels.) link.

Overall, I hope to correct my understanding such that my program can find the mean shape that minimizes the sum of square distances of the vertices in the ellipsoid set, which does not seem to be accomplished at the moment as the alignment does not factor in the orientation of the other ellipsoids. Any suggestions?

[image: Scatter plot of perturbed ellipsoids]

[image: Average ellipsoid described by GPA]